# Can you multiply or divide standard errors?

Tags: error

I'm running a regression in R, and the way it is set up, I get a series of coefficients and their terms.  As it happens, I know that one coefficient is the quotient of two terms (coef1 = r/k).  The output gives a standard error for coef1.  the term r also appears elsewhere in the output, thus I know the standard error of r.  Since coef1 = r/k, and I know the value and standard error of coef1 and r, and I also know the value of k, is it possible to calculate the standard error of k?

Comment: No, you need the joint distributions

Comment: I'm confused by your question. $k$ is a variable and you have observed it's values, do you need the standard deviation of $k$? Just compute it directly. I assume you mean you need the standard deviation for the regression coefficient that comes from adjusting for $k$ in the model.

Comment: This question is difficult to understand because it appears to use "r" and "k" interchangeably for the *variables* and their *estimated coefficients.*  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

From the way you've written the question I assume that you have two input variables $r$ and $k$ and you have estimated the linear model:

$$ E[Y|r, k] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (r/k) + \beta_2 r $$

Ordinary least squares (and pretty much most regression models) give asymptotic normal distributions with estimable variances for the parameter estimates:

$$ \sqrt{n} \left[ \hat{\beta} - \beta \right] \rightarrow_d \mathcal{N} \left( 0, \text{var}(\beta) \right) $$

And in running the regression model, you come up with two estimates: $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{\text{var}}(\hat{\beta})$, both of which are consistent for the things they're estimating.

I understand further that *now* you're interested in what a regression parameter would have been for $k$ had you estimated it in a model like $E[Y | r, k] = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 k$. You noticed mathematically that, technically speaking $\beta_1 * \beta_2 = \alpha_1$ so $\hat{\beta_1} * \hat{\beta}_2$ is an estimator of $\alpha_1$. But how can you use the regression model results to estimate the variance of $\hat{\beta_1}*\hat{\beta_2}$?

There is no *exact* result, however the $\delta$-method gives you an approximation. You simply need to calculate the Jacobian of $ J = \nabla f(x, y)$ where $f(x,y ) = x * y$ and multiply with the covariante $\text{var} \left( \hat{\beta_1} \hat{\beta_2} \right) \approx J^T \hat{\text{var}}(\hat{\beta}) J$.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that $E(\hat{\beta}_1\hat{\beta}_2)=E(\hat{\beta}_1)E(\hat{\beta}_2)+\text{Cov}(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)={\beta}_1{\beta}_2+\text{Cov}(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)$

Comment: @Glen_b What about the second moment of the product? The OP needs an estimate of the variability, thus their question about "multiplying standard errors" (which would be the wrong approach as I argue).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me rather that @Larry is trying to estimate a model that looks like:

$$ E[y|x_1,x_2] = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2x_2,$$

where it is a priori known that $\alpha_1=\beta_1/\beta_2$ and $\alpha_2=\beta_1$. By fitting an OLS regression, we get the estimates $\hat\alpha_1$ and $\hat\alpha_2$ and corresponding standard errors. And using these estimate we can calcualte, $\hat\beta_2=\hat\alpha_2/\hat\alpha_2$. The question seems to be "what is the standard error of $\hat\beta_2$?".

A practical approach to estimating the standard error would be simply to bootstrap $\hat\beta_2$. If your sample has $n$ observations, resample $n$ of them *with replacement* (according to the design by which the sample was obtained). Call this resampled set of observations $S$. Then fit your model on $S$ and calculate your estimate of $\hat\beta_2^{(S)} = \hat\alpha_2^{(S)}/\hat\alpha_1^{(S)}$. Repeat this process many times, each time drawing a sample from your original $n$ observations with replacement. Say you have fitted your model to $k$ resampled datasets. This will give you $k$ different $\hat\beta_2^{(S)}$s. The standard deviation of the distribution of these estimates will give you an approximation to the the standard error of $\hat\beta_2$.

Comment: This may be a good answer but the question seemed to be about multiplying or dividing standard error estimates which may not be advisable.